# Wait for protractor to load data opened in new tab

Tags: javascript, protractor

I have a scenario where when I click on a element in website A it opens in Website B in a new tab. I am able to navigate to the new tab that is Website B but have to use browser.sleep() which my client wants me to avoid using. I tried using promises like after element(Website A).click().then(function(){getallwindowshandle, then move to the window of my choice}); but here too I had to use browser.sleep()

Can someone please help me how can I overcome browser.sleep() when navigating to new window with protractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is using **protractor.ExpectedConditions** for wait until a target element is visible or enabled or so on. Using protractor's expected conditions you can make protractor to wait until next tab is ready to proceed. You can follow below code:

**Code**

```
   EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;

   targetEleOnNewTab=element(locator)//find out an element on new tab
   //keep this line of code after switching to new tab before performing any 
   //operation on new tab
   browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(targetEleOnNewTab),15000,'Ele Not Visible');
```

Comment: I have many pages that will open in tabs. It will not be ideal for the application that am working to get a specific element on a webpage to be found and then find the title of that page. Also my webpages are quite dynamic that the element could be something else or somewhere else in the page the next time that I run the test script. I basically want ideally a generic function that would spit out the current page's title without taking anything as input.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is a little bit older I'd like mention how I solved this problem:

```
var handles;
const targetNumberOfTabs = 2; // Or whatever
try {
     await browser.wait(
       async function() {
          handles = await browser.getAllWindowHandles();
          if(handles.length >= targetNumberOfTabs) {
                  return true;
           }
           else {
                  return false;
           }
        }
       ,30000, 'The number of tabs should be equal or greater ' + targetNumberOfTabs);
}
catch(err) {
       console.log(err);
       // Whatever you might want to do on error
}
```

Basically this code makes the test flow wait till the number of expected tabs has been reached for a maximum of 30 seconds.

Requirements: You need to know how many tabs you expect to be there and store them in `targetNumberOfTabs`. And your environment needs to support `async`/`await`.